# CacheFilterAttribute MVC /What is Cached

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributes

Suppose I am using `CacheFilterAttribute`

See http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2008/03/28/asp-net-mvc-action-filter-caching-and-compression.aspx

Suppose I am returning partial views filled with data from the controller.

If the data is updated in the databse, will I get the updated data?

What is cached, is it the total response or just the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the data is updated in the databse, will I get the updated data?

No.

> What is cached, is it the total response or just the files?

The HTML markup that was rendered to the client the last time before it was cached.

Answer (score 1):

I agreed @Darin's comments. Instead of using CacheFilterAttribute you can use OutputCache.

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    [HandleError]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [OutputCache(Duration=10, VaryByParam="none")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

Or you can create output cache profile and specify this web.config file.

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute(v=vs.108).aspx